# jQuery animation function timing

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

Feel like I'm overlooking the obvious here...

I've got several vars set up like so:

```
var productOne = function () {
          $(".product2").fadeIn(200).animate({"right": "+=75px"}, 500, "easeOutElastic").delay(3000).fadeOut(200).css("right", "0");
          $(".product-text.two").fadeIn(200).delay(3500).fadeOut(200);
        }

var productTwo = function () {
          $(".product2").fadeIn(200).animate({"right": "+=75px"}, 500, "easeOutElastic").delay(3000).fadeOut(200).css("right", "0");
          $(".product-text.two").fadeIn(200).delay(3500).fadeOut(200);
        }
```

etc...Then I want to fire them in order, like so, and loop back to the first:

```
       window.setInterval(function() {
          $(productTwo);
          $(productThree);
          //and so on
      }, 5000);
```

but they all fire at the same time. How can I put a specific number of ms between each function call?

Comment: What do you mean by `loop back to the first`?

Comment: @Abe Miessler: He wants to run productOne, productTwo, productThree, productOne, productTwo, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fire each one off from the end of the previous one. So productOne would setTimeout to call productTwo, and productRwo would setTimeout to call productThree, and productThree to call productOne.

ETA Example:

```
var productOne = function () {
      $(".product2").fadeIn(200).animate({"right": "+=75px"}, 500, "easeOutElastic").delay(3000).fadeOut(200).css("right", "0");
      $(".product-text.two").fadeIn(200).delay(3500).fadeOut(200);
      setTimeout(productTwo, 5000);
    }

var productTwo = function () {
      $(".product2").fadeIn(200).animate({"right": "+=75px"}, 500, "easeOutElastic").delay(3000).fadeOut(200).css("right", "0");
      $(".product-text.two").fadeIn(200).delay(3500).fadeOut(200);
      setTimeout(productThree, 5000);
    }
```

Comment: I had just started to try that, but my syntax was all over the place. If I wanted the products to fade out, and the next to fade in, where does the setTimeout call enter in?

Comment: If they are consecutive animations, then they need to be on the callback of the animation. If the timing is sufficient to cover the animation time, then it is just the end part of the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
// initial product count
var product = 1;

// function which select which animation to call
function fire_product( product ) {

    switch ( product ) {

        case 1:
            $(productTwo);
            break;

        case 2:
            $(productTwo);
            break;

        case 3:
            $(productThree);
            break;

    }

    // go to next product next time
    product++;

    // reset to first product when we reach the last product
    if (product > 3) product = 1;

    // self-call this function again
    setTimeout( function() {
        fire_product( product );
    }, 5000);

}

// call the function for the first time with desired parameter
fire_product( 1 );
```

Comment: This seems like the best way to edit the timing on one line - haven't written a switch, or even native JS, in awhile, very nice, thx much.

Comment: As far as I know this is the best alternative to the setInterval method, which is not much reliable. If you are going to do different jQuery animations one after the other, you should use chain them, or use the callback functions to wait for the previous one to finish before starting the new one. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you want animations to fire in order then you should call the next one from the complete callback function.  Example:

```
 $(".product2").fadeIn(200).animate(
    {"right": "+=75px"}, 
    500, 
    "easeOutElastic",
     function() {
    // call your next animation here.  Add delays here if you want...
  }).delay(3000).fadeOut(200).css("right", "0");
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  Does someone see a problem with my solution?  If so, please let me know what it is

Comment: I up-voted your answer because I believe it is more in the spirit of how animations _should_ work, and you don't have to define named functions for each sequence in the animation.